# Can dynamic feature delivery be implemented in a React-based app converted to Android using Capacitor?

Tags: java, android, reactjs, capacitor, dynamic-feature-module

I have three React-based apps converted to Android. I want to merge them into a single app. One of these apps will serve as the base, while the other two will be feature modules with on-demand delivery. Is there a way to achieve this?

I don't have any prior knowledge of React or Capacitor. but I tried everything in my way but it ended up with disappointment

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.